# Extending BASH completion with Python Click

Tags: command-line-interface, bash-completion, python-click

I'm wanting to customize the BASH completion functionality of my Python Click CLI program to include not only the commands / subcommands of the script, but also objects that the script creates.

Let's say my program is called `cli-tool`, and it can create object `foo` using the command:

```
cli-tool object create foo
```

For simplicity, let's say the command simply concatenates the argument string (`foo` in this case) to a text file of the same name located in `~/.cli-tool/objects/foo`. Doing `cat ~/.cli-tool/objects/foo` would then print `foo` in your terminal.

What I would like for the tool to do is when I then type:

```
cli-tool object get <TAB><TAB>
```

The terminal would then list `foo` and any other files that live inside `~/.cli-tool/objects`.

For the record, I have read the [Python Click 6.x stable documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/6/bashcomplete/), which clearly states:

> Currently, Bash completion is an internal feature that is not
>   customizable. This might be relaxed in future versions.

What I was hoping is that there would be a way to extract the **full** BASH completion script from the following command:

```
eval "$(_CLI_TOOL_COMPLETE=source cli-tool)"
```

And then customize it myself. I've also seen the [click-completion](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-completion) project, but I'm not sure what it does beyond extending the completion for Zsh and Fish shells.

Has anyone achieved the type of completion I mention above?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [click-completion](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-completion), this is quite straight forward.

#### Code:

Import and `init()` Click Completion:

```py
import click
import click_completion

click_completion.init()
```

Then instantiate a [`click.Choice`](https://github.com/click-contrib/click-completion) object:

```py
option_type = click.Choice('obj1 obj2 obj3'.split())
```

In the case of your option directory, pass in a list of the appropriate items instead of the example *obj1-obj3*.

Then pass the option type to the `click.argument()` decorator like:

```py
@click.argument('option', type=option_type)
```

And don't forget to activate your completion with your shell.  The click variation for bash is [here](http://click.pocoo.org/6/bashcomplete/#activation):

#### Test Code:

```py
import click
import click_completion

click_completion.init()

option_type = click.Choice('obj1 obj2 obj3'.split())

@click.group()
def cli():
    """My Cool Tool"""

@cli.group(name='object')
def object_group():
    """Object subcommand"""

@object_group.command()
@click.argument('option', type=option_type)
def get(option):
    click.echo('option: {}'.format(option))


commands = (
    ('"" object get ""', 1),
    ('"" object get ""', 2),
    ('"" object get ""', 3),
    'object get obj1',
    '--help',
    'object --help',
    'object get --help',
)

os.environ['BASH_COMP'] = 'complete'

import sys, time
time.sleep(1)
print('Click Version: {}'.format(click.__version__))
print('Click Completion Version: {}'.format(click_completion.__version__))
print('Python Version: {}'.format(sys.version))
for cmd in commands:
    try:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print('\n-----------')
        print('> ' + str(cmd))
        time.sleep(0.1)

        if len(cmd) == 2:
            os.environ['COMP_WORDS'] = cmd[0]
            os.environ['COMP_CWORD'] = str(cmd[1])
            cli(complete_var='BASH_COMP')
        else:
            try:
                del os.environ['COMP_WORDS']
                del os.environ['COMP_CWORD']
            except:
                pass
            cli(cmd.split())


    except BaseException as exc:
        if str(exc) != '0' and \
                not isinstance(exc, (click.ClickException, SystemExit)):
            raise
```

#### Results:

```
Click Version: 6.7
Click Completion Version: 0.4.1
Python Version: 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

-----------
> ('"" object get ""', 1)
object
-----------
> ('"" object get ""', 2)
get
-----------
> ('"" object get ""', 3)
obj1    obj2    obj3
-----------
> object get obj1
option: obj1

-----------
> --help
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  My Cool Tool

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  object  Object subcommand

-----------
> object --help
Usage: test.py object [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Object subcommand

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  get

-----------
> object get --help
Usage: test.py object get [OPTIONS] OPTION

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

Comment: Thanks again for the great feedback! I'll clarify because I didn't explain very well. I'm wondering how to add completion for the names of the objects created. Another example: for Kubernetes there's `kubectl`. I can type `kubectl get pods ` and then hit `<TAB>` a few times. I'll then get a list of pods deployed. That information can only come from querying the Kubernetes API since pod names are always changing. This means the completion script for `kubectl` will query the API for a list of pod names, and return that as a completion. I'm wondering if that's possible in Click.

Comment: I understood you.  The example above does everything needed except the querying.  You will need to generate that list of strings via the k8s api, and then pass it to `click.Choice()`.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you for the clarification. Does that mean instead of passing `'obj1 obj2 obj3'.split()`, I would pass a function that returns a list of objects I want to be autocompleted? To use my simple example, if I used `click.Choice(os.listdir("~/.cli-tool/objects/foo"))`, the files inside of `~/.cli-tool/objects/foo` would then be listed as an autocomplete if I typed `cli-tool object get <TAB><TAB>` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  A list of strings passed in will be the valid choices.  Those valid choices are what the command completion uses.

Answer (score 2):

For Click 8.1.3, you can use either of [Overriding Value Completion](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/#overriding-value-completion) or [Custom Type Completion](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/#custom-type-completion).

Here's an example from the [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/) where you can use a custom `shell_complete` function. It must return a list of [`CompletionItem`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.shell_completion.CompletionItem) objects, or as a shortcut it can return a list of strings.

```py
def complete_env_vars(ctx, param, incomplete):
    return [k for k in os.environ if k.startswith(incomplete)]

@click.command()
@click.argument("name", shell_complete=complete_env_vars)
def cli(name):
    click.echo(f"Name: {name}")
    click.echo(f"Value: {os.environ[name]}")
```